# Powershell ISE - How do I copy many files and rename them at the same time?

Tags: file, powershell, copy, rename

I'm trying to use Powershell ISE to help me do the following:

- Perform a search for many files (with an extension of *props.tmpl) under a certain folder and to include all sub-directories.
- When found, I want to copy that file to its current location, but with an extension of *.tmpl2 (what I really want is to skip this step and copy *props.tmpl to a file called *props)
- Then rename all *.tmpl2 files and remove the tmpl2 entirely, leaving just the *.props extension.

Ideally, what I want is to copy existing files to the same directory with a new name. It seems like all of the searches I've ran on Powershell ISE are not coming up with the right info I need (or I'm not searching for the right way to do it - trying 'powershell ise copy many files with new names' didn't help.

I had the replacement piece down and working, but I no longer want to eliminate the original tmpl files (they are templates so I may want to review them later for their original content).

What I was doing to replace them was this:

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter "*props.tmpl" -Recurse |
   Rename-Item -NewName { $_.name -replace '.tmpl',''}
```

Which works great other than completely removing the original file.

I started trying to piece something together, but I'm not understanding how to properly name the copy and stopped at this point with just an error (this was an attempt to skip the extra copy and just simply rename the copy instead of adding the extra step of '*.tmpl2'):

```
# Get all *props.tmpl files
Get-ChildItem -Filter "*props.tmpl" -Recurse |

# Iterate through each found file
ForEach-Object {
    Copy-Item $_.name |
        Rename-Item -NewName { $_.name -replace '.props.tmpl','.props' }
}
```

Any help would be really appreciated (not much of a Powershell guy, but I'm trying to learn since powershell tends to be a little more dynamic then oldschool batch scripts).

Thanks in advance

---

Final version of this script per help from @ssennett

Here's my final version:

```
# Get all *props.tmpl files
Get-ChildItem -Filter "*props.tmpl" -Recurse |

# Iterate through each found file and copy it to non-template form in same location
ForEach-Object {
    Copy-Item $_.FullName ($_.Name -replace '.tmpl','')
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not too far from the answer! It's just how Copy-Item is being handled.

Without a Destination being specified, the Copy-Item will effectively try and copy the file onto itself. Instead of piping it to Rename-Item, you can handle the renaming with the -Destination parameter, as below.

```
$files = Get-ChildItem -Filter "*props.tmpl" -Recurse
$files  | % { Copy-Item -Path $_.FullName -Destination ($_.Name -replace 'props.tmpl','.props') }
```

This would copy a file called *RandomFileprops.tmpl* into another file *RandomFile.props*. If you want to remove the original, you can use the **Move-Item** cmdlet with the same parameters, which effectively renames the original file.

Comment: Just realized, I should clarify: The % after the pipe is an alias for "Foreach".